# Esc key to press a button: works if an alert() is fired in the function; otherwise Esc has to be pressed multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a ColdFusion application, I have an Exit button on each page. Sometimes the exit button invokes some cleanup in the app and sometimes, when cleanup isn't necessary, it just loads the previous calling page of the app. My customer requested that he be able to hit the Esc key to go back. (I've told him NOT to use the back arrow in the browser because then the cleanup doesn't happen when it is necessary. Hence, I can't listen for Esc and then use history.back). My solution was to listen for the Esc key and then get jquery to press the Exit button already on the page. I did this by adding a class of "exit" to the Exit button, and putting the following script in the head section of the page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            const key = event.key;
            if (key === "Escape") {
                pressExitKey();
            }
        })
    })
    function pressExitKey() {
        alert('Press Esc Again to Exit');
        $(document).find('input.button.exit').click();
    }
</script>
```

The script as it is written works. Of course, it takes pressing Esc TWICE to fire the Exit button. (Once to close the alert window, and again to fire the exit button. But here is what I don't understand. The only reason I put the alert in there in the first place is that without it, the Esc button has to be hit a seemingly unpredictable amount of times before the event fires and the Exit button is pressed. If there is a pattern to the number of times it has to be pressed, I have not been able to determine it.

The effect can be reproduced by commenting out the alert statement in the script.

Leaving the alert in there at least produces a consistent result. I easily can tell the customer, "You can either press the Exit button, or hit Esc twice." That's better than telling him to "hit the Esc button again and again until the Exit happens." Either way, it looks or feels sloppy. (It's an eyesore for the alert to popup, and it's annoying to press Esc over and over an unpredictable number of times.)

**Edited:**
My question is: why does leaving out the **alert** cause the user to press Esc over and over (an unpredictable and inconsistent number of times) before the event fires?

Comment: i) Could be an issue of input focus. Have you tried to put a `console.log()` in your keydown event listener to print out when a key is hit? ii) Maybe some other element (input?) on your page is swallowing the ESC keypress (by calling https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/#event-stopPropagation) so it never reaches your event listener.

Comment: @mIi Yes. When I put a console.log('keydown') and comment out the alert in the pressExitKey function, it logs 'keydown' over 20 times and never fires the pressExitKey function unless I press and hold down the Esc key. I don't really understand this. I thought maybe the Esc key is used for too many things, so maybe I should use something else, like Ctrl-X as the exit key. To do this, what should I test for instead of `if (key === "Escape")` to test for `Ctrl-X' ?

Comment: @mli The above comment was mentioning you, but I wasn't sure what the "L" character was and couldn't edit the comment after 5 minutes. Apologies. I'm not very experienced with this.

Comment: I forgot that `Ctrl+X` is a special key for "cut". So perhaps `Alt+X` would be a better key combination to test for? If so, how would I test for it instead of `if (key === "Escape")` in the listener?

Comment: put a debugger to replace the alert so you can see what is trigging the infinite looop

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyC. But when I dropped the use of the `Esc` key, opting instead for pressing `Alt+x`, the code worked and there was no further need for the alert.  (See my answer and new approach below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works, using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> as the triggering keystroke instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I do have a question about this. I'll put it at the bottom after the code. Credit for this idea goes to @BrockAdams. Many thanks.

```
document.addEventListener ("keydown", function (zEvent) {
  if (zEvent.altKey && (zEvent.key === "x" || zEvent.key === "X")) {  // not case sensitive
    pressExitButton();
  }
})

function pressExitButton() {
  $(document).find('input.button.exit').click();
}
```

The question: If I include this script in the `application.cfm` template, the script will be included at the top of every page in the application. The question is, will adding the listener at the top of every page stack up somehow and eat memory or cause some conflict? If so, how would I prevent this?

Comment: If you have it in being output in the onRequestStart() function, it should only be written once.  Are you retrieving other HTML via Ajax that might bring it in?

I might recommend re-architecting to use some sort of layout operation.  (This is how the Coldbox framework does it.)  That would prevent multiple inserts of the script.  I don't believe that's your issue, though.

Comment: @WillBelden I have never used the Coldbox framework. My main question now is if it matters that the code is in the application.cfm template, which runs at the top of every page CF serves. I believe that makes each page a stand-alone DOM of its own and so it shouldn't matter that every page creates the handler. I haven't noticed any slow down if there is some. If I'm wrong about my assumptions here, I hope someone will tell me. The script code is only written once: in application.cfm, which loads as sort of a "pre-include" at the top of every page served.

Comment: I know many CF programmers would groan at the unorthodox approach. But this is an Intranet application, already 6 years in development, so SEO and security are not major concerns. I'll show it to the customer tomorrow and get his feedback on the look and feel of it.

Comment: Customer loves it and no one else has posted a comment, so I'm going to go ahead and accept my own answer. I'm still open to comments, however, if anyone thinks of something I should know or consider. Thanks everyone.